# Using underscore in Postgresql LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql, padding, sql-like, sqldatatypes

I am trying to use underscores in a postgresql LIKE to perform a search for particular pattern of data but it does not seem to work.

The client is version 9.2.21 and the server is on version 9.4.12.

For example,

```
select * 
from table1 
where f1 like '___'
```

returns nothing even when there is clearly a match in the table--i.e, there is data with a value that matches--e.g. `f1 = '123'`.

I am wondering if there is a system config / parameter that influences this behaviour?

Or can this be explained some other way?

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: It is char(9) type

Comment: the values are just an example. Can be alpha.

Answer (score 6):

Values stored in columns defined as `char(9)` will be padded with blanks to the defined length. So when you store `'123'` in that column, it actually stores `'123      '`

You need trim those trailing blanks:

```
where trim(f1) = '___'
```

But you should avoid the `char` type completely. It offers no advantage whatsoever over `varchar` but has several disadvantages (you just found one)

Comment: . . Doesn't `char()` save a byte or two (by not encoding the length) when all the values have the same number of characters -- say, if all are ISO-standard country codes?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: no it doesn't. They are stored in absolutely the same way (except that `char()` is stored padded.

Comment: Interesting.  In most databases, `char()` saves on a length byte or two.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know about "most", but it definitely saves nothing in Postgres or Oracle.

Comment: why does displaying the field value of char type show no padding? Like `SELECT '>>' || f1 || '<<'` in above example would show no padding.